# Machine learning concepts clarification (linear regression)

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm pretty new to machine learning and after watching some videos i wanted to make sure i understood a few concepts:

1. When it comes to linear regression, we can find the intercept and the coefficients using several methods such as: Gradient Descent, Normal Equation and Least Squares.
2. Then, to measure the accuracy of our hypothesis function derived from the step above, we can use methods such as R-Square or  Square Error.
3. When it comes to regularization - we can use Ridge Regression (for example) to find the coefficients and intercept in addition to help us eliminate overfitting.
   After applying Ridge Regression, when we get some coefficients that are 0, that just means they are not "that crucial" for our data and so we could simply remove them from our hypothesis function.

Are all of these statements correct?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All correct.  One slight modification to your rhetoric:

when we get some coefficients that are 0, that just means they are not "that crucial" for our data and so we could simply remove *the corresponding features* from our hypothesis function.